# html form to asp login

Tags: html, asp.net, aspxgridview

I am trying to forward a simple html form login to an ASPX site. This is my form

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="frmLogin" method="post" action="default.aspx">
<input type="text" name="username" id="login-usr"><br>
<input type="password" name="password" id="login-pwd">
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" id="btnLogin">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The data does not copy over to the aspx login.

Comment: Because the names don't match, probably? What have you tried?

Comment: @codecaster I copied the names from the form using the developer tab in chrome

Comment: @codecaster this is the login form that I’ve tried, but When the aspx site loads it just refreshes